# how to enable Comments in lightbox or colorbox

Tags: media

Is there a way to make comments on a node (photo) available when lightbox or colorbox is in action? I mean how can you make a comment box appear underneath a node (e.g. Facebook)? I am using drupal 7 and zen sub theme. Thank you in advance.